# Intellij Git commands not working

Tags: git, intellij-idea

There is a problem with git integration in my Java project in Intellij. When I try to perform a commit, it doesn't matter if I changed anything, there is always the same message: "No changes detected". Moreover, when I try to pull something, there is no action whatsoever. In Version Control tab in Intellij, there is only one message: "Default updating...".

However, when I'm using git bash, everything is working as it is supposed to be.
What might be the problem here?

Comment: Take a look at the version control settings.  They must be off.  IntelliJ integrates seamlessly with Subversion and Git.  When I have problems, I find that it's usually not the IDE.

Comment: Are the Git action menu options not greyed out when you right click?  Or, are you saying you could not even choose commit and this is why it failed?  In any case, this sounds like the plugin is the problem and not Git.

Comment: @duffymo I agree but the OP said in this case `when I'm using git bash, everything is working as it is supposed to be.`.  Strange.

Comment: Not strange.  The bash shell doesn't know about the IntelliJ configuration for version control.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, they're not. I mean, the most important ones, such as commit, stash changes, fetch, pull or add. Some of them are grayed out though.

Comment: If this happened to me, I would reconfigure Git in IntelliJ from scratch, step by step.  There is a smell in your setup, and you just need to find what it is.  In the meantime just use the bash, it seldom gets corrupted in my experience. +1

Comment: Check the logs, probably there is some VCS-related exception.

Answer (score 1):

The stuck-in-updating symptom looks similar to the corrupted update - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178309.

If it happened after an update, this is probably it. Check the logs, probably the ClassNotFound exception will be there. If so, make a clean install

Comment: This is probably the answer for my problem. Indeed, ClassNotFoundException is in log file. What do you mean by making a clean install?

Comment: Ok, I uninstalled and installed Intellij, and now it's working. Thank you so much!