# Can't view info in Local Changes and Log on Version Control tab (git) in Intellij Idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea

My Idea stopped showing local changes and history from the git. I tried File > Invalidate Caches/Invalidate and Restart, but did not help.
Previously worked! 
There are no error messages, just an endless attempt to update the view. 
See image of problem:
[image]

[image]

log from IDE. I do not observe any problems in the console of git.
Also I tried to clone the new project into a separate folder, when I open new project  I see the same problem.

```
2017-10-03 19:18:49,907 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-10-03 19:18:49,997 [     90]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - User scale factor: 1.0 
2017-10-03 19:18:49,997 [     90]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - System scale factor: 1.0 (IDE-managed HiDPI) 
2017-10-03 19:18:50,097 [    190]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-172.4343.14, 26 Sep 2017 09:49) 
2017-10-03 19:18:50,097 [    190]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 7 (6.1, amd64) 
2017-10-03 19:18:50,097 [    190]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b12 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2017-10-03 19:18:50,097 [    190]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.152-b12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2017-10-03 19:18:50,307 [    400]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CommunityEdition\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CommunityEdition\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5\lib\boot.jar -Didea.platform.prefix=Idea -Didea.jre.check=true -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2017.2 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\user\java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\user\java_error_in_idea.hprof 
2017-10-03 19:18:50,307 [    400]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CommunityEdition\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5\jre64\lib\ext: [access-bridge-64.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2017-10-03 19:18:50,307 [    400]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNU charset: Cp1251 
2017-10-03 19:18:50,757 [    850]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 450 ms 
2017-10-03 19:18:50,917 [   1010]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2017-10-03 19:19:20,674 [  30767]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2017-10-03 19:19:25,623 [  35716]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin 'CVS Integration' can't be loaded because: Plugin is disabled 
2017-10-03 19:19:25,653 [  35746]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin 'Subversion Integration' can't be loaded because: Plugin is disabled 
2017-10-03 19:19:25,673 [  35766]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin 'Ant Support' can't be loaded because: Plugin is disabled 
2017-10-03 19:19:25,673 [  35766]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin 'hg4idea' can't be loaded because: Plugin is disabled 
2017-10-03 19:19:25,843 [  35936]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 33 plugins initialized in 12757 ms 
2017-10-03 19:19:25,853 [  35946]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.2.3), Bytecode Viewer (0.1), Copyright (8.1), Coverage (172.4343.14), Eclipse Integration (3.0), EditorConfig (172.4343.14), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (172.4343.14), Gradle (172.4343.14), Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java (172.4343.14), IDEA CORE (172.4343.14), IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (172.4343.14), JavaFX (1.0), Kotlin (1.1.4-release-IJ2017.2-3), Maven Integration (172.4343.14), Plugin DevKit (1.0), Properties Support (172.4343.14), Settings Repository (172.4343.14), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), UI Designer (172.4343.14), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), YAML (172.4343.14) 
2017-10-03 19:19:25,853 [  35946]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: Scala (2017.2.7) 
2017-10-03 19:19:25,853 [  35946]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Disabled plugins: Ant Support (1.0), CVS Integration (11), Subversion Integration (1.1), hg4idea (10.0) 
2017-10-03 19:20:12,745 [  82838]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=705 
2017-10-03 19:20:12,875 [  82968]   INFO - tellij.util.io.storage.Storage - Space waste in C:\Users\user\.IdeaIC2017.2\system\caches\attrib.dat is 4363561 bytes. Compacting now. 
2017-10-03 19:20:14,474 [  84567]   INFO - tellij.util.io.storage.Storage - Done compacting in 1599msec. 
2017-10-03 19:20:14,984 [  85077]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CommunityEdition\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2017-10-03 19:20:15,134 [  85227]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2017-10-03 19:20:16,574 [  86667]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState - Registry values changed by user: 
2017-10-03 19:20:16,574 [  86667]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState -   SBT.system.in.process = true 
2017-10-03 19:20:28,599 [  98692]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2017-10-03 19:20:31,299 [ 101392]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2017-10-03 19:20:32,085 [ 102178]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2017-10-03 19:20:38,736 [ 108829]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:5176 
2017-10-03 19:20:38,908 [ 109001]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:172 
2017-10-03 19:20:41,215 [ 111308]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:1939 
2017-10-03 19:20:41,216 [ 111309]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
2017-10-03 19:20:43,219 [ 113312]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2017-10-03 19:20:52,472 [ 122565]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 94 application components initialized in 99396ms 
2017-10-03 19:20:52,847 [ 122940]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 171857 ms 
2017-10-03 19:21:16,817 [ 146910]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:37906 
2017-10-03 19:21:21,965 [ 152058]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0 
2017-10-03 19:21:25,189 [ 155282]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2017-10-03 19:21:25,199 [ 155292]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [] - [<Project>] 
2017-10-03 19:21:25,199 [ 155292]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [<Project>] 
2017-10-03 19:21:29,941 [ 160034]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:13120 
2017-10-03 19:21:32,794 [ 162887]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader@5a9f37d4 
2017-10-03 19:21:39,182 [ 169275]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 182 project components initialized in 36334 ms 
2017-10-03 19:21:39,994 [ 170087]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader@177e7414 
2017-10-03 19:21:41,384 [ 171477]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 4 module(s) loaded in 2202 ms 
2017-10-03 19:21:45,235 [ 175328]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader@5a906feb 
2017-10-03 19:21:48,836 [ 178929]   INFO - CompilerBackwardReferenceIndex - backward reference index version differ due to: class java.io.FileNotFoundException 
2017-10-03 19:21:54,159 [ 184252]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - OpenFilesActivity run in 1140ms under project opening modal progress 
2017-10-03 19:21:54,339 [ 184432]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 630ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 0/1 sluggish, 1/1 very slow 
2017-10-03 19:21:54,689 [ 184782]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - InitToolWindowsActivity run in 530ms under project opening modal progress 
2017-10-03 19:21:54,849 [ 184942]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - ProjectStartupRunner run in 160ms under project opening modal progress 
2017-10-03 19:21:54,999 [ 185092]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 2720ms; general responsiveness: 0/2 sluggish, 2/2 very slow; EDT responsiveness: 0/2 sluggish, 1/2 very slow 
2017-10-03 19:21:55,779 [ 185872]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - [kts] loading script definitions [] using cp:  
2017-10-03 19:21:55,879 [ 185972]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - Templates provider KotlinCompilerScriptTemplatesSettings is invalid:  
2017-10-03 19:21:56,449 [ 186542]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - Templates provider Gradle Kotlin DSL is invalid: Unable to get Gradle home directory 
2017-10-03 19:21:56,449 [ 186542]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - Templates provider Gradle Script Kotlin is invalid: Unable to get Gradle home directory 
2017-10-03 19:21:56,449 [ 186542]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - [kts] loading script definitions [kotlin.script.templates.standard.ScriptTemplateWithArgs] using cp:  
2017-10-03 19:21:59,090 [ 189183]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - C:/Users/user/Projects/AutoTests/gwautotesting/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2017-10-03 19:22:01,750 [ 191843]   INFO -                git4idea.GitVcs - Git version: 2.14.2.0 
2017-10-03 19:22:03,381 [ 193474]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 61687 ms 
2017-10-03 19:22:03,481 [ 193574]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 9122ms; general responsiveness: 0/10 sluggish, 2/10 very slow; EDT responsiveness: 3/9 sluggish, 5/9 very slow 
2017-10-03 19:22:04,755 [ 194848]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [<Project>] 
2017-10-03 19:22:05,381 [ 195474]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Some post-startup activities freeze UI for noticeable time. Please consider making them DumbAware to do them in background under modal progress, or just making them faster to speed up project opening. 
2017-10-03 19:22:05,381 [ 195474]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - ProjectInspectionProfileStartUpActivity run in 616ms on UI thread 
2017-10-03 19:22:06,421 [ 196514]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - ExternalSystemStartupActivity run in 1040ms on UI thread 
2017-10-03 19:22:08,771 [ 198864]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - GradleStartupActivity run in 2350ms on UI thread 
2017-10-03 19:24:00,047 [ 310140]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
Exit code 1 
2017-10-03 19:26:01,688 [ 431781]   INFO - .script.IdeScriptEngineManager - javax.script.ScriptEngineManager initialized in 1300 ms 
2017-10-03 19:30:11,772 [ 681865]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git ls-remote took 30166 ms. Command parameters: 
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CommunityEdition\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false ls-remote https://user%40ti.local@stash.tcsbank.ru/scm/toi/gwautotesting.git 
2017-10-03 19:33:04,421 [ 854514]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 20 project components initialized in 100 ms 
2017-10-03 19:33:22,586 [ 872679]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 182 project components initialized in 110 ms 
2017-10-03 19:33:22,586 [ 872679]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2017-10-03 19:33:23,146 [ 873239]   INFO - CompilerBackwardReferenceIndex - backward reference index version differ due to: class java.io.FileNotFoundException 
2017-10-03 19:33:23,176 [ 873269]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [<Project>] 
2017-10-03 19:33:23,196 [ 873289]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 0ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-10-03 19:33:23,206 [ 873299]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/gwautotesting/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2017-10-03 19:33:23,406 [ 873499]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 947 ms 
2017-10-03 19:33:23,657 [ 873750]   INFO -                git4idea.GitVcs - Git version: 2.14.2.0 
2017-10-03 19:33:23,678 [ 873771]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [<Project>] 
2017-10-03 19:33:23,878 [ 873971]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 150ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-10-03 19:33:23,878 [ 873971]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - [kts] loading script definitions [] using cp:  
2017-10-03 19:33:23,888 [ 873981]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - Templates provider KotlinCompilerScriptTemplatesSettings is invalid:  
2017-10-03 19:33:23,888 [ 873981]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - Templates provider Gradle Kotlin DSL is invalid: Unable to get Gradle home directory 
2017-10-03 19:33:23,888 [ 873981]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - Templates provider Gradle Script Kotlin is invalid: Unable to get Gradle home directory 
2017-10-03 19:33:23,888 [ 873981]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - [kts] loading script definitions [kotlin.script.templates.standard.ScriptTemplateWithArgs] using cp:  
2017-10-03 19:33:24,528 [ 874621]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 650ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-10-03 19:33:24,528 [ 874621]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 2524 files to update 
2017-10-03 19:33:42,860 [ 892953]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 18332ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-10-03 19:35:18,020 [ 988113]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2017-10-03 19:35:18,310 [ 988403]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2017-10-03 19:35:18,370 [ 988463]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 0ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-10-03 19:35:18,490 [ 988583]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 120ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-10-03 19:35:33,427 [1003520]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
Exit code 1
```

Comment: Has it happened after an update?
Please see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/46525225/7523979 helps.

Comment: @DmitriySmirnov no. It happened just in process work. I recently updated the application to the latest version (2017.2.5) but it did not help.

Comment: Check the logs for possible errors then. Maybe the git calls are not finishing or taking long. ACtually, antivirus could affect this, so it is worth disabling it for testing, if any.

Comment: In case it was not clear, Dmitriy is referring to IntelliJ IDEA's logs. You can get to them via _Help > Show Log in Explorer/Finder_. 
Also... Does other Git functionality work within IntelliJ IDEA? Can you run git commands from a console? Any problems with other Git Projects? Answers to those questions may indicate a network issue, corrupted Git executable, corrupted git files in the project, or problems with the git server.

Comment: @DmitriySmirnov I do not observe any problems in the console of git.
Also I tried to clone the new project into a separate folder, when I open new project  I see the same problem.
Maybe the problem lies in the following: "backward reference index version:" due to: class java.io.FileNotFoundException "

Comment: Problems with cloning and the opening of this project on another PC does not arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem:
use command **`git rm -r --cached .`** in git console.
In this way I cleaned the git cache.